# Most reliable sources telling whether movies are true to the Christian faith?

Tags: christian-living, resource-request, culture

I watch “Christian” movies sometimes and am inspired and filled - popular film, historical fiction or other fiction genres. Sometimes the movie ends up being propaganda pushing un-biblical heresy, or anti-Christian in other subtle ways. The reviewers themselves are not immune to this issue, and “family friendly” is not a guarantee. What person or group would be best, or even good, for correctly telling us in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few decades ago I relied on the excellent but now discontinued [USCCB Movie Reviews](http://archive.usccb.org/movies/movieall.shtml).  I highly recommend those reviews, which were professionally written as by a newspaper movie critic.

For newer movies, a quick Google search yields the following result:

- [Catholic News Service](https://www.catholicnews.com/movie-reviews/)
- [movieguide.org](https://www.movieguide.org/category/watch-reviews)
- Focus on the Family's [pluggedin.com](https://www.pluggedin.com/movie-reviews/)

**Note**: Feel free to edit this answer to add more Christian review websites.

Comment: Thanks great. While we’re here in the comments, any readily available good ones come to mind (if interested). I’ll check out usccb right away

Comment: @AlBrown I should probably add that the USCCB review focus is more for identifying unsuitable elements (like profanity, sex, gratuitous  violence) rather than how the movie exemplifies / subverts Christian faith, trusting that the moviegoer can discern on his/her own.  Longer review seems to focus more on how well the movie is made using the same criteria as a professional movie critic.  If you're looking more for content evaluation, the Focus on the Family website maybe more suitable for you.

Comment: Ok good. I did start to find that with usccb. Thanks

Comment: Is probably asking a lot to find someone saying whether a film is faithful to the bible

Comment: @AlBrown Yes, we probably need to find those in scattered blogs covering individual movies rather than a central place where one can consistently find Christian evaluation of the content.  Most centralized place see their main mission as more to flag un-Christian sexual, profanity, unnecessary violence, and drugs.  Fortunately Google makes it a LOT easier to find those scattered articles compared to 20-30 years ago when USCCB was the only one available.  My hope that better indexes like imdb.com or rottentomatoes.com will include those scattered Christian reviews.

Comment: @AlBrown I'm not sure about the site policy, but maybe you can bring up individual movie that purports to be a Christian movie as a question in C.SE and solicit the community's input.  Another way is to bring it up in the [Upper Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room) chat although the audience is a lot more limited.